# Error in downloading dependency from 2 mirrors in Maven

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I want to download [spring-native](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.experimental/spring-native/0.9.2) dependency from maven mirror as it is not in my third party mirror.I tried to do it by including maven mirror in my settings.xml file,but it doesn't work.

Settings.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings>
   <mirrors>
      <mirror>
         <id>artifactory</id>
         <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
         <url>https://thirdparty.com/artifactory</url>
      </mirror>
      <mirror>
         <id>MavenCentral</id>       
         <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
         <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      </mirror>
   </mirrors>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>artifactory</id>
         <repositories>
            <repository>
               <id>central</id>
               <url>http://central</url>
               <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
               </releases>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
               </snapshots>
            </repository>
            <repository>
               <id>MavenCentral</id>
               <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/</url>
            </repository>
         </repositories>
         <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
               <id>central</id>
               <url>http://central</url>
               <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
               </releases>
               <snapshots>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
               </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
         </pluginRepositories>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
   <activeProfiles>
      <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
   </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I added this dependency-

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.experimental</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-native</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Issue-
*Cannot resolve org.springframework.experimental:spring-native:0.9.2*
How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `<mirrorof>*<mirrorof>` then you essentially override all other mirrors and repository definitions. To exclude repositories from the mirror, use

`*,!otherrepo`